# Ajax / PHP Notice: Undefined index:

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, http-post

Pulling my hair out with this.  Suddenly receiving the following error which wasn't there before:

```
>>PHP Notice:  Undefined index: rmvFileList in C:\wamp\www\somesubdirectory\members\delete.php on line 7
```

This is coming from an Ajax submission to delete.php.  Although the "notice" is appearing, the script is executing properly as it should (database deletion completed correctly, file deleted correctly, and the success call being logged correctly in the console.log).  Probably just some sort of sick obsession, but I want to get rid of the warning popping up in my error log every time the delete script is called.

Here is the ajax:

```
var rmvFile = "Some file name";

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "delete.php",  
dataType:"text",                
data: {'rmvFileList' : rmvFile },
success: function(returnData) {
console.log(returnData);
}
});
```

And here is delete.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('../../phpincl/db.php');

$table = 'phoeteo_img_' . $_SESSION['memberID'] . '_' . $_SESSION['showID'];

$name = $_POST['rmvFileList'];  <<--This is line 7

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE imgNameTime = '$name'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $toBeDeletedIndex = $row['imgIndex'];
    $toBeDeletedFilename = $row['imgNameTime'];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM $table WHERE imgNameTime = '$name'";

    mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die('Failed: ' . mysqli_error($conn));

    $path = 'repository/' . $_SESSION['memberID'] . '_' . $_SESSION['showID'] . '/' . $toBeDeletedFilename;

    unlink($path);
}

echo $name;
?>
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: Try to to print out $_POST

Comment: Are you able to forcibly reproduce this problem using the ajax code you provided? I suspect a crawler is hitting that page instead without the post params.

Comment: Or, the form is somehow submitting twice, once with ajax, and once with the original form using GET instead.

Comment: Thanks so much for the tips / hints.  It was indeed being called twice, once from droponejs and once again from my own script.  $_POST was being cleared off by one.  Completely forgot about the second call, which is needed but by incorporating the isset condition mentioned by Priyank, everything is now working and no error messages are being generated.

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

set **isset** in php:check code below :

```
if(isset($_POST['rmvFileList'])){
$name = $_POST['rmvFileList'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE imgNameTime = '$name'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$toBeDeletedIndex = $row['imgIndex'];
$toBeDeletedFilename = $row['imgNameTime'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM $table WHERE imgNameTime = '$name'";

mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die('Failed: ' . mysqli_error($conn));

$path = 'repository/' . $_SESSION['memberID'] . '_' . $_SESSION['showID'] . '/' . $toBeDeletedFilename;

unlink($path);
}

echo $name;
 }
```